# How do I configure a default driver for UnixODBC?

Tags: odbc, driver, unixodbc

I would like to configure my `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files to allow a default driver to be used if no driver is specified by the connection. I assume it's possible given the common error message when no driver is specified:

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002)
```

But my DuckDuckGo-foo fails me. I tried setting a `[DEFAULT]` in `odbc.ini`:

```
[DEFAULT]
Driver=Snowflake
```

But still got the error (Due to the [remainder of the configuration](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch/tree/master/snowflake/conf), "Snowflake" is a valid driver that works when I specify it.) I tried also adding a `[DEFAULT]` section to `odbcinst.ini`, but it made no difference.

So how does one go about specifying a default UnixODBC driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [discussion on @TallTed's pull request](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch/pull/16) I've come to the conclusion that it is not possible to configure a default driver in the unixODBC configuration files, sadly, despite the assertions of the [ODBC default driver subkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/install/default-driver-subkey), which I think @TallTed properly interprets in [their answer](/a/57102585/79202). Perhaps in the future, but for now, at least, I think I have simply misunderstood the meaning of the error message:

```
Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

I had been assuming that this meant that no default driver was configured on the host. But I think now perhaps, what it actually means is "Cannot find the DSN in the URL, and there was no `Driver` param to fall back on, either". IOW, the `Driver` param specifies the default driver if the DSN can't be found.

That interpretation is consonant with the findings discussed in the PR. It's a little disappointing, but I think it could be fixed by an improved error message, or at least some sort of documentation update to explain how to specify a default driver.

Answer (score 0):

Given [your existing configuration files](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch/tree/master/snowflake/conf) (both `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini`), I believe you'll find success by adding the following (as described in [the ODBC spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/install/default-driver-subkey?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)) to `odbcinst.ini` --

```
[Default]
Driver=Snowflake
```

-- and the following (as described in [the ODBC spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/install/default-subkey?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)) to `odbc.ini` --

```
[Default]
Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=Snowflake
Locale=en-US
SERVER=SF_ACCOUNT.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
ACCOUNT=SF_ACCOUNT
```

Comment: Oh, the opposite of what I tried (two lines in `odbc.ini` and the dupe section in `odbcinst.ini`. Sadly it does not appear to work for me, at least not with DBD::ODBC. :-( Will keep futzing with it, though.

Comment: This sure looks like the right answer, but sadly does not work. I still get the error “Data source name not found, and no default driver specified.” If I explicitly pass `Driver=Default` in my connection string, it does find it, though it of course complains that the `Snowflake` library does not exist. Works fine when I pass `Driver=Snowflake`. :-(

Comment: @theory - I would suggest that you update the configuration files we have to look at, so we can understand what you're trying and/or have tried.  You need not replace the current files; adding pairs like `1.odbc.ini` and `1.odbcinst.ini`, and `2.odbc.ini` and `2.odbcinst.ini`, would let us see things clearly. Small typos are hell in these config files, and impossible to resolve with "I tried xyz" unless we can see the missing/extra character/line/whatever.

Comment: I've pushed them to [this branch](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch/tree/odbc-default/snowflake/conf).

Comment: @theory - [PR#16](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch/pull/16) submitted with the changes I think will bring success. `Driver={Snowflake Driver}` *might* need to be `Driver=Snowflake Driver` or `Driver=/usr/lib/snowflake/odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so`.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like there is no support for a default driver in unixODBC, to judge by the discussion in the [PR](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch/pull/16). :-(